# SharePoint Online Set-PnPListItem - Unable to set Enterprise Keywords / TaxKeyword value

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to set enterprise keyword on a file using PowerShell but it's not working. below is the command I'm using:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Item.Id -Values @{"TaxKeyword"="4992bb31-d492-4e07-821c-dee7448a4605"}
```

The commands executes without error. But the Keyword is not added to the file. I've renamed Enterprise Keyword to Tags.

```
$SiteURL = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/OCDev"
$ListName = "New Clients"
$SiteRelativeURL = "/NewClients/Ash1/X/B/TestExcel.xlsx"
$Tag = "4992bb31-d492-4e07-821c-dee7448a4605"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId "clientID" -Tenant 'tenantname.onmicrosoft.com' -Thumbprint "certificate thumbprint"
$Item = Get-PnPFile -Url $SiteRelativeURL -AsListItem
Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Item.Id -Values @{"TaxKeyword"="4992bb31-d492-4e07-821c-dee7448a4605"}
```

Commands executes without errors:

[image]

But Keyword isn't added:

[image]

Tested on another site with out of the box Enterprise Keywords name and still does not work.
Tried running the command from a different server, nogo.

Comment: are you perhaps using an old version of the module? I see this issue https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1191 with the same problem referring to an old version

Comment: I saw that thread too, its from 2017 and I installed mine last year. Will update it and try again, thanks.

Comment: I was wondering how do you know that `TaxKeyword` as Key correspondes to the "Tags" in the screenshot you're showing there?

Comment: That's the field internal value by default, you can also verify that by going to edit that column.

Answer (score 2):

That cmdlet is no longer supported. Solution is to use this command:

```
Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue -ListItem $Item -InternalFieldName 'Enterprise Keywords' -TermId xxxxx-da3d-4b41-be2a-ae01f7bcc8de
```

Credit to RaytheonXie_MSFT for answering my question here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187868/sharepoint-online-set-pnplistitem-unable-to-set-en?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1185542#newest-answer-comment